# Using Wordpress: I want to display related articles of a query(post) result on index page using tags

Tags: wordpress

After a certain wp_query which will only display the first result (Breaking News), I want to get the result (Breaking News) tags to display related articles to the first result.

So if **Doggies protest of no adoption** is the first result in my first query, I want to get tags of **Doggies protest of no adoption** to query db so has to display other **Doggies adoption** story and display them. This is on index.php page not single.php page.

[please see image for pictorial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtMdd.png)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to query posts with the same tags as the first result?

Comment: Yes. I want to query posts with the tags of result of first query.